# trouble constructing "select(*) > 0 from SomeTable where .." in scala slick 1.0.1

Tags: scala, slick

I'm trying to generate a sql statement like this:

```
select count(*)>0 from "SomeTable"
```

using Scala's slick 1.0.1 and postgres.

This is my code:

```
val rows = for(row <- Query(Order)) yield row
println(rows.selectStatement)
val rowCount = (for(l<- Query(rows.length)) yield l).take(0)
println(rowCount.selectStatement)
val e = for(l<-rowCount.take(0)) yield l> 0
println(e.selectStatement)
```

but it's generating queries like the following:

"rows" seems to be generated as expected:

```
select x2."ID", x2."truck_id", x2."pickup", x2."user_uid", x2."user_provider", x2."status" from "Orders" x2`
```

rowCount sure is odd.

```
 select x2.x3 from (select count(1) as x3 from (select x4."ID", x4."truck_id", x4."pickup", x4."user_uid", x4."user_provider", x4."status" from "Orders" x4) x5) x2 where false -->for "rowcount".
```

e is an unholy beast as well.

```
select x2.x3 > 0 from (select count(1) as x3 from (select x4."ID", x4."truck_id", x4."pickup", x4."user_uid", x4."user_provider", x4."status" from "Orders" x4) x5) x2 where false  ->  huh....weird.
```

I'm not quite certain, but it seems to me I don't quite grok aggregate/grouping functions(such as count(*)) and Scala slick.  Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: I'm confused by the `>0` part.  What are you trying to accomplish with that?

Comment: I'm more confused by the `yield row.length` part

Comment: yeah, I'm sorry about that.  I'll update with a simpler example